# Simple Batch File Homework

Tags: batch-file

So i have this simple homework of doing a batch file that shows 3 options, and an error message for the entry for the option. so far it seems simple for me. I saw a youtube video and according to what i know it suppose to run ok but the problem is that when I run it and choose option 2 it opens also option 1, and when I choose option 3 it doesn't exit the program. And when I choose a parameter that is not specify the error message do not show. I am gonna copy paste  my batch file because is easy to understand.

```
@echo off

echo Choose an option:
echo.
echo 1)Open Disk cleanup

echo 2)Open Disk Defragmenter

echo 3)Exit
echo.

Set /p Op=Write the option:

if %op%==1 (
start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe
) 
else if %op%==2 (
start %windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe
)
else if %op%==3 (
exit
) 
else (
    cls
    echo Error not defined
)   
pause
```

Is there something that I am missing or wrote wrong please let me know. If you can copy paste and run it in your computer and tell me if it is working fine because something tell me that in the process of learning I try a few times and i think I messed up with something that suppose to run correctly the file since my instructor told me that we have to be careful when using the commands in a batch file.

Comment: None of your code is proper `IF...ELSE` syntax.  The syntax is clearly defined in the help file for the `IF` command.  Open up a command prompt and type `IF /?` to read the help file. Regardless of that it seems like it would be just as easy to have three `IF` commands with no `ELSE` at all. `if %op%==1 start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe` and `if %op%==2 start %windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe` and `if %op%==3 exit`

Comment: yes, thanks it almost work the only problem that i have is with the error message to show if another value is indicated.

Comment: I would advise you to use the `CHOICE` command instead.  If you do, it will not allow the user to enter an invalid option.

Answer (score 3):

Your code formatted correctly but is susceptible to command injection because of the usage of the `SET /P` command.

```
@echo off

echo Choose an option:
echo.
echo 1)Open Disk cleanup

echo 2)Open Disk Defragmenter

echo 3)Exit
echo.

Set /p Op=Write the option:

if "%op%"=="1" (
    start "" "%windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe"
) else if "%op%"=="2" (
    start "" "%windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe"
) else if "%op%"=="3" (
    exit /b
) else (
    cls
    echo Error not defined
    pause
)
```

A best practice solution which handles invalid input options.

```
@echo off
echo Choose an option:
echo.
echo 1)Open Disk cleanup

echo 2)Open Disk Defragmenter

echo 3)Exit
echo.

choice /C 123 /N /M "Select an Option:"
set "op=%errorlevel%"

if "%op%"=="1" start "" "%windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe"
if "%op%"=="2" start "" "%windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe"
if "%op%"=="3" exit /b
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it with this code.

```
@echo off

echo Choose an option:

echo.

echo 1)Open Disk Cleanup Utility

echo 2)Open Disk Defragmenter

echo 3)Exit

echo.

Set /p op/3=Write the number option:

if %op/3%==1 (
start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe
) 

if %op/3%==2 (
start %windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe
)

if %op/3%==3 (
exit
)

else (
    cls
    echo Error not defined
)   
pause
```

the only problem that I have is that the error message appears even though options 1 and 2 are selected, it executes the options but it also shows the error message. I only want that the error message to show if any of those parameters aren't chosen.
I know that else is responding because if I choose option 1 else it executes because is not number 2 or 3. What it comes to my mind is if it is possible to define the op variable in an enumeration format like a group set of options.

Comment: I clearly stated in my previous comments that the proper `IF...ELSE` syntax is clearly defined in the help for the `IF` command. I even told you how to read the help.  You are not using the correct `IF... ELSE` syntax.  I fixed your code for you and gave you an alternate solution as well. What was wrong with the two code solutions I provided?

Comment: the thing is that the first try that I try your code it did not work. Now that I try it again it worked, so probably I did something wrong when I copy paste your code. But i already figure it out a little different with a few changes. Thanks for the help.